# Launching nao_driver

Tags: ros, nao-driver, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

When I type "roslaunch nao_driver nao_driver.launch" to start the nao driver nodes. I am getting the following error:

```
auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [8981]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 66760138-255a-11e1-9695-68a3c41a4ebd
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [8994]
started core service [/rosout]
process[nao_walker-2]: started with pid [8997]
process[nao_sensors-3]: started with pid [8998]
process[nao_controller-4]: started with pid [8999]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/ros/nao_driver/scripts/nao_controller.py", line 45, in <module>
    import actionlib
  File "/home/user/ros/common/actionlib/src/actionlib/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from action_client import *
  File "/home/user/ros/common/actionlib/src/actionlib/action_client.py", line 61, in <module>
    from actionlib_msgs.msg import *
ImportError: No module named actionlib_msgs.msg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/ros/nao_driver/scripts/nao_sensors.py", line 44, in <module>
    from sensor_msgs.msg import JointState
ImportError: No module named sensor_msgs.msg
T    raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/ros/nao_driver/scripts/nao_walker.py", line 50, in <module>
    from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
ImportError: No module named geometry_msgs.msg
================================================================================REQUIRED process [nao_controller-4] has died!
process has died [pid 8999, exit code 1].
log files: /home/user/.ros/log/66760138-255a-11e1-9695-68a3c41a4ebd/nao_controller-4*.log
Initiating shutdown!
================================================================================
[nao_controller-4] killing on exit
[nao_sensors-3] killing on exit
[nao_walker-2] killing on exit
[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

Can anyone help me with that?
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12319/launching-nao_driver/) by [Maya A](https://answers.ros.org/users/1530/maya-a/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

nao_driver depends on the [common_msgs](http://www.ros.org/wiki/common_msgs) stack, which contains the missing files mentioned in the output. nao_driver also depends on [humanoid_msgs](http://www.ros.org/wiki/humanoid_msgs) and [nao_msgs](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nao_msgs), so make sure that you install these dependencies first.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Osswald](https://answers.ros.org/users/1042/stefan-osswald/) with karma: 281 on 2011-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2011-12-13**:
To verify the packages are correctly found, simply run "roscd actionlib_msgs", "roscd geometry_msgs" and "roscd humanoid_msgs". All should end up in a valid directory in your ROS installation.